# How to import and use exported const?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an exported const in `Components.ts` file which I happily use in `Module.ts` without any problems:

**Components.ts**

```
import { TestComponent } from './Components/TestComponent';

export const ComponentList = [
    TestComponent
];
```

**Module.ts**

```
import { ComponentList } from './Components';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ComponentList
    ]
})
```

I want to use this const in a component but I'm getting `Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'` error:

**MyComponent.ts**

```
import { ComponentList } from '../Components';

constuctor(){
    console.log(ComponentList); // <--error line
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I use this const in my component?

Comment: It sounds like you have a cycle somewhere in your module dependencies.

Comment: Does it work if you put it in a file by itself? `exportedconst.ts` for example.